# How to replace a small matrix in a larger matrix with different rows and columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose we have a large `A(n*n)` and a small `B(m*m)` matrices (`m<n`). Also, there is a set `J`  with the size of `m` which are values from `{1,2,3,...,n}`. I want to replace the matrix B in rows and columns of matrix A such that the first row (column) of matrix B is replaced in the first element of set `J`. For example,

```
   [[1 1 1 1 1],
    [1 1 1 1 1],
A = [1 1 1 1 1],
    [1 1 1 1 1],
    [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

and

```
J = [1, 3, 5]
B =[[2 3 4],
    [5 6 7],
    [8 9 10]]
```

Then, the result will be:

```
   [[2 1 3 1 4],
    [1 1 1 1 1],
A = [5 1 6 1 7],
    [1 1 1 1 1],
    [8 1 9 1 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
tmp = A[J-1]
tmp[:, J-1] = B
A[J-1] = tmp
```

```
>>> A
array([[ 2,  1,  3,  1,  4],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 5,  1,  6,  1,  7],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 8,  1,  9,  1, 10]])
```

Why the roundtrip using a `tmp` variable, where the more intuitive way would be `A[J-1][:, J-1] = B`?  That is because `A[J-1][:, J-1]` cannot be a view of `A` (there is no simple striding of `A` that will give you that sub-array), and thus it is instead a view of a copy of `A[J-1]` (which you can use as lvalue but will be lost).  So, instead, we explicitly "put back into A" the value of `tmp`.

Comment: Dear Pierre. Thank you so much. Great explanations

Answer (score 0):

will the obvious way of doing things cut it?

```
A = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
J = [1, 3, 5]
B = [[2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 10]]

print(A)
for rB,rA in enumerate(J):
    for cB,cA in enumerate(J):
        A[rA-1][cA-1] = B[rB][cB]   #list indices are 0-based
print(A)
exit(-1)


#ok, let`s do it functional way
J = list(map(lambda x:x-1, J))  # convert inex array 0-based indices
lira = lambda l,i,r,a: r if type(l) is not list else lira(l[:i[0]] + [lira(l[i[0]], a, r[0], a)] + l[i[0] + 1:], i[1:], r[1:], a) if i else l
A = lira(A,J,B,J)
print(A)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I wanted to avoid using for loop

Comment: Sorry i on`t know how to add a formatted comment and had to edit an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `np.ix_` for this purpose:

```
A[np.ix_(J-1,J-1)] = B
```

output:

```
array([[ 2.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 5.,  1.,  6.,  1.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 8.,  1.,  9.,  1., 10.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, Ehsan. Easy approach. Mamnoon